# Remove (.unrst) file from the Eclipse/petrel simulation?

Tags: petrel

I am running my simulations with Eclipse E100, and the run generates a file with extension .unrst which takes a lot of space in the folder 
Is there a way to stop the simulation from generating this file 
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want unified restart files select summmary, .UNSMRY (unified) or .Snnnn,  or non-unified restart (.Xnnnn).

FMTOUT for format and/or UNIFOUT for unification ([Details](http://petrofaq.org/wiki/Eclipse_Output_Data)).